# Keycloak | Cannot await on updateToken() in async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jboss, keycloak

We are developing Spring application with React/Redux frontend. We successfully integrated it with Keycloak authentication service. However, we encountered unwanted behaviour after access token timed out. Our restMiddleware looks like this (simplified):

```js
    function restMiddleware() {
    return (next) => async (action) => {
       try{

            await keycloak.updateToken(5);

            res = await fetch(restCall.url, {
                ...restCall.options, ...{
                    credentials: 'same-origin',
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + keycloak.token
                    }
                }
            });

       }catch(e){}
    }
```

The problem is, that after token expires and updateToken() is executed, async function does not stop and invokes fetch() immediately, before new access token is received. This of course prevents fetch request from succeeding and causes response with code 401. updateToken() returns a Promise, so I see no reason why await would not work on it, which certainly is happening.

I confirmed that function in `updateToken().success(*function*)` will execute after successful token refresh and placing fetch() inside it would solve the problem, but because of our middleware construction I cannot do that. I developed this workaround:

```js
    function refreshToken(minValidity) {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            keycloak.updateToken(minValidity).success(function () {
                resolve()
            }).error(function () {
                reject()
            });
        });
    }

    function restMiddleware() {
    return (next) => async (action) => {
       try{
            await refreshToken(5);

            res = await fetch(restCall.url, {
                ...restCall.options, ...{
                    credentials: 'same-origin',
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + keycloak.token
                    }
                }
            });

       }catch(e){}
    }
```

And it works, but it is not elegant.

The question is: why the first solution didn't worked? Why I cannot await on updateToken() and have to use updateToken().success() instead?

I suspect this might be a bug and to confirm this is the main purpose of this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`updateToken` method's documentation states that it returns a `Promise`, but it actually isn't a `then`able and thus the `await` keyword does not think it as a valid `Promise`. This is how I would put it. :)

Your solution seems elegant to me and I have done the exact same thing also to correctly continue on a `Promise` chain after calling the `updateToken` function.

Keycloak JavaScript adapter documentation: https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/documentation/securing_apps/topics/oidc/javascript-adapter.html

Comment: I just looked into the keycloak.js, where this method is defined and I can see the point. What updateToken() returns is not a Promise (as from ECMAScript specification) at all. It is some custom object containing only success() and error() functions which Keycloak creators named... "promise object" -.- 

"The updateToken method returns a promise object which makes it easy to invoke the service only if the token was successfully refreshed and for example display an error to the user if it wasn’t." 

It is very confusing, in my opinion they shouldn't be using this description.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, as said, keycloak.js uses a homegrown promise implementation that is incompatible to the ES6 Promise. What I tend to do in my projetcs is a little helper like this one here (TypeScript).

```
export const keycloakPromise = <TSuccess>(keycloakPromise: KeycloakPromise<TSuccess, any>) => new Promise<TSuccess>((resolve, reject) =>
    keycloakPromise
        .success((result: TSuccess) => resolve(result))
        .error((e: any) => reject(e))
);
```

and use it like

```
keycloakPromise<KeycloakProfile>(keycloak.loadUserProfile())
    .then(userProfile => ...)
    .catch(() => ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `promiseType` option upon initialization of the keycloak client defaults to `legacy`.

If you change it to `native` then you should get an ES6 promise after the
`refreshToken` invocation

```js
    keycloak
      .init({
        onLoad: 'login-required',
        promiseType: 'native',
      })
      .then(() => {//...})
      .catch((err) => {//...})
```