# Wait for result of async operation

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

I had such API for async requests

```
 request(pathParams, params, method, callback, error) {

        ...........

        return $.ajax({
            ...requestAttrs,
            url: url,
            data: params,
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            type: method,

            success: callback,
            error: error
        })
    }
```

But due to some requirements I need to change it to

```
request(pathParams, params, method, callback, error) {

            ...........
            someAsyncFunction(function(){
                return $.ajax({
                ...requestAttrs,
                url: url,
                data: params,
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                },
                type: method,

                success: callback,
                error: error
            })      

            })

        }
```

**I hope you see my problem. In the previous case I was using the value returned from `$.ajax` call - for example because I would cancel those requests.**

But now when I need to put my ajax function inside another async function, 
I can't return the $.ajax value like I did previously (because now I moved return inside `someAsyncFunction`).

Is there a way I could possibly first run that `someAsyncFunction` inside request, wait for its completion and then return `$.ajax` as I was doing before?

is something like stratified.js library usable for this?

---

`someAsyncFunction` is `updateToken` function from [here](http://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.1/securing_apps/topics/oidc/javascript-adapter.html). Basically I need to put what I had in `request` before, inside the success callback of `updateToken` - but the problem is I can't return the `$ajax` now as I did before.

Comment: it really depends on what the heck `myAsyncFunction` actually **does** - without knowing that, the answer is potato

Comment: @JaromandaX It is updateToken function from keycloack (http://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.1/securing_apps/topics/oidc/javascript-adapter.html). and basically I need to put what was before in `request` in success callback of that updateToken.

Comment: if you `return someAsyncFunction(function() { ...})` and someAsyncFunction returns the result of the callback, which is the return value of $.ajax, then you'll be golden

Comment: I don't see `someAsyncFunction` in that page you linked to - so, potato

Comment: @JaromandaX See updated question please.

Comment: you can't `return` from an async function. find a way to use another callback function instead of `return`

Comment: @JacobGoh stratified js does that

Comment: so how and where did stratified js does that ?

Comment: Let me see if I understand correctly. You want to define a function `request`. When called as, e.g., `request(pathParams, params, method, callback, error).then(processContent)`, it should `updateToken`; when it finishes, call `$.ajax`; when that finishes, invoke `processContent` with the data received by `$.ajax`. Is that correct?

Comment: @Amadan I do not want to change current signature of `request` function and the current signature of it is that it returns $.ajax - as it is in first code snippet. However, the $.ajax needs to run only when someAsyncFunction a.k.a updateToken  returns success.

Comment: It does not return `$.ajax`, it returns a `Promise` that `$.ajax` creates. Returning a different promise (which involves having fulfilled the `$.ajax` promise) is not "changing current signature".

Comment: @Amadan I think you understood correctly just to point you out what my existing code was using return value of $.ajax for is that I would cancel those requests sometimes. I still need that functionality.

Comment: @Amadan THanks I will investigate it. just for record I have this quote if it is relevant : "I just looked into the keycloak.js, where this method is defined and I can see the point. What updateToken() returns is not a Promise (as from ECMAScript specification) at all. It is some custom object containing only success() and error() functions which Keycloak creators named... "promise object" -.". from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45610720/keycloak-cannot-await-on-updatetoken-in-async-function

Comment: Ah. In that case, the function that promisifies `keycloak.updateToken` at the bottom of @mersocarlin's answer is indeed the way to go.

Comment: @Amadan Can you please show me small example how I could use mersocarlin's answer with abort? (as I indicated in my first code example where I was able to abort return value of `request`).

Comment: Which version of jQuery?

Comment: @Amadan it is version 3.1.1

Answer (score 2):

I took the liberty to change your code a little bit.

My approach is to separate code as much as possible so you don't get into the [Callback Hell](http://callbackhell.com/).

1. Create `someAsyncFunction` and make whatever you judge necessary so then you can return its value
2. Same applies to your `ajax` call. In case it needs the output from `someAsyncFunction` then it's very easy to send them as well
3. [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for the win! Chain all your calls and keep your code's flow :)

*I'm using `setTimeout` so they look asynchronous*

```js
function someAsyncFunction() {
  return new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('-> someAsyncFunction has finished')
      
      const token = 'abc123'
      resolve(token)
    }, 1000)
  ) 
}

function executeAjaxRequest(pathParams, params, method, token) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('-> executeAjaxRequest has finished')
      resolve()
    }, 2000)
  })
}

function request(pathParams, params, method) {
  someAsyncFunction()
    .then((token) => executeAjaxRequest(pathParams, params, method, token))
    .then(() => console.log('-> end!'))
}

request('pathParams', 'params', 'method')
```

Sample code `someAsyncFunction` and `keycloak` thing :)

```
function someAsyncFunction() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    keycloak.updateToken(30)
      .success(resolve)
      .error(reject)
  })
}
```

Comment: please check updated question (bottom) where I specify what someAsyncFunction is.

Comment: @user200300 It doesn't matter what `someAsyncFunction` is or does. As long as you call `resolve` when it finishes you are good to go :)

Comment: @mersocarlin: It kind of does matter: his `someAsyncFunction` is actually a function that returns a promise (and does not take a callback like in his example code), so manually constructing a promise and resolving it is not even needed.

Comment: I was using return value of $.ajax before because I needed to cancel (e.g. using .abort()) those requests sometimes, can I still do that?

Comment: Just saying, it's more complicated than it needs to be. `function request(...) { return keycloak.updateToken(30).then(token => $.ajax(...)) }` - why construct a promise around a promise?

Comment: @Amadan I don't know how to handle `keycloak`. To be honest, I've never heard of it. If returns a promise already then fine, otherwise I just made an example of how it can work.

Comment: @Amadan it does take a callback, why not? check sample: `keycloak.updateToken(30).success(function() {
    loadData();
})`

Comment: Me neither, I just read the relevant portion of the docs OP linked. :P

Comment: @user200300 yes you can. Simply change `executeAjaxRequest` in my example and use your `$.ajax({...})` code

Comment: That is not "taking a callback". Taking a callback: `foo(callback)`. Returning a promise: `foo().then(callback)`. With a promise, `then` takes a callback, not your function. They are two very distinct patterns.

Comment: @mersocarlin i will investigate but if I can call .abort on the result of `request` as I did before it will be nice.

Comment: My apologies, apparently their "promise" is not a `Promise`. Your `someAsyncFunction` is completely correct and warranted.

Comment: @Amadan No worries :) As I didn't know exactly how it should work I decided to wrap it on a Promise and bring it to a more known scenario.

Comment: @mersocarlin Can you please expand your example such that you could show how I would use the `abort` now on the `request` function?

Comment: @user200300 Doesn't Amadan's answer solve your problem?

Comment: @mersocarlin yes I think it does.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I see where your problem is. Apologies for not thinking it through. The jqXHR that `$.ajax` returns functions in two ways: both as a promise, and also as a handle where you can abort it before it is done. The first requires we return it, so that we can continue the promise chain. The second requires we retain it, so we can get at it outside the promise chain.

```
function authenticateWithKeycloak() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    keycloak.updateToken(30)
      .success(resolve)
      .error(reject)
  })
}    

function request(...) {
  let promise = authenticateWithKeycloak();
  promise.abort = () => { promise.aborted = true; }
  return promise.then(authenticated => {
    if (!promise.aborted) {
      let xhr = $.ajax({...});
      promise.abort = () => xhr.abort();
    }
    return promise;
  })
}

let reqPromise = request(...);
reqPromise.then(...);
reqPromise.abort();
```

EDIT: allowed aborting before AJAX.

Comment: one question: when I call abort as above, what if the we are in the middle of `updateToken` call? what will it abort then?

Comment: It would raise an error, because `xhr` would not exist yet. We can fake a NOP-on-abort `xhr` before, with `promise.xhr = { abort: () => void 0 }` before `promise.then`. Or you can check existence of `xhr` before trying to abort. There might be more options.

Comment: Ah so it is tricky actually because before I was relying a lot on the abort functionality to avoid some race conditions. But now if user does abort, there is a chance that the operation he/she intended to abort will not abort, because, say he/she clicked abort at the wrong time? (i.e. at the time when updateToken was running). is my reasoning above correct?

Comment: I see what you mean. How about now?

Comment: Out of interest, I think we could have also done this without promises, e.g. using something like this: http://codepad.org/HNaV2TfK

Comment: @user200300: You could, if you go with `success` and other callback-style options. Promises make it nicer. Also, depending on how `.abort` is written, `returnObj.abort = ret.abort;` might or might not work, because of `this` binding. To be safe, `returnObj.abort = ret.abort.bind(ret)`.

Comment: good point on bind. Other than that I think my code works, just updateToken has `then` instead of callback, that is what you meant?

Answer (score -1):

You may want to do like this. Hope this fits your case. If I misunderstood it, pls ping in the comment.

Here, I just returned a string, you can edit to return the ajax request.

```js
function someAsyncFunction(callback)
{
    //do something
    
    return callback();
}
function request(pathParams, params, method, callback, error) {
    return someAsyncFunction(function(){
            return "Ajax request";    
    });
}

console.log(request());
```

Comment: please see updated question where I specify what someAsyncFunction is